# Why did Git stopped tracking added files in sub directory?

Tags: git

I have a sub directory that has suddenly stopped tracking new file additions.
If I change a filename, it sees it has been deleted and all changes to existing files are being tracked.
Other new files are being tracked in different sub directories...

I am not using sub modules and there is no `.git` directory in the affected sub directory

I have tried to do a `git update-index --really-refresh` and it did nothing.

I am using git extensions under windows.

How would you troubleshoot that situation?

Comment: Is this a wrong `gitignore` file? As in http://stackoverflow.com/a/4618962/6309.

Comment: no the gitignore is fine i've done a status check and that dir is not being ignored

Comment: So the `git status --ignored -- path/to/your/dir` doesn't show the untracked files? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6795813/is-there-a-way-to-have-ignored-files-show-up-in-git-status or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/466764/show-ignored-files-in-git)

Comment: No It does show that it is ignoring it

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what happened with it but I changed the name of the folder and the new files were tracked again. It appears that the name of the folder was polluted somehow. Does anyone know of a way to fix this and my answer for the time being is just to change the folder name.

Comment: There are three ignore files, .gitignore, .git/info/excludes and ~/.gitexclude. Check each one - probably you got the name into one of these files. You may even have modified core.excludesfile to make a custom ignore file - so check for that too. See the gitignore manual for the full set.