# Cannot merge/checkout because of ghost untracked capitalized files

Tags: git

So, i am getting the

```
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:
```

But the listed files are existing files only with a different casing, eg section.js exist, Section.js is showing as untracked.

`git status` is clean and shows no untracked files, I've tried `git reset --hard` but nothing. I've even tried

```
git config --global core.ignorecase true
```

But the ghost wrong-cased files are still shown as untracked. What can I do? Is this a bug?

Comment: Does this maybe help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4610561/untracked-files-not-shown-in-git-status

Comment: Are you using a case-sensitive file system, in which you can create two different files named, e.g., `readme.txt` and `README.txt`? Or are you on a system where, if you currently have a `README.txt` and ask the system to create `readme.txt`, it destroys `README.txt` instead and puts your new contents into that file?

Comment: Internally, Git doesn't use the file system in the usual way, so Git can and will hold two files whose name differs only in case. The `core.ignorecase` setting is so that Git can tell what your system will do if it tries to create such files. It does not tell Git *to* ignore casing, it tells Git whether *your computer's filesystem* ignores casing. (This means you should not set it ... and setting it globally has no effect as each Git repository has its own private setting, created by Git when Git created the repository.)

Comment: If I'm reading your posting correctly, your work-tree actually contains a lowercase name, `section.js`, while `git status` is saying that it contains an uppercase named, `Section.js`. If that is the case, perhaps something has gone wrong with the file system monitor option on your OS. See the `--no-fsmonitor` option for `git update-index`.

Answer (score 0):

Think I had this exact issue when a file on our `develop` branch was merged in with a name all lowercase, and then a follow up PR was made to update the casing for that filename. Afterwards, attempts to checkout `develop` would be met w/ an error:

```
git checkout develop
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:
    src/path/to/file/that/use/to/be/lowercase.ts
Please move or remove them before you switch branches.
Aborting
```

And yet, `git status` shows nothing,`reset --hard` did nothing, `git clean -n` showed nothing.

I suspect it's cause my local version of the branch was made obsolete after the new change got in. What ended up working for me -- and this'll sound dumb -- is just deleting my `develop` branch locally, and just pulling it  down from the main repo again.